# Bootstrap modal dialog not showing

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have problem with not showing third Forgot password modal. It is linked from second modal - in Forgot Password

First two modals work normal, third is working if i delete data-dismiss="modal" from  tag, but you can previous window behind forgot password. If i have data-dismiss="modal" in a tag the only thing happens is that the background of the app is darker (like in first two modal) but there is no modal/ dialog for forgot password.

Can someone please check

```
<form method="post" id="singupform">
<div class="modal" id="singupModal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header"></div>
            <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 id="myModalLabel">Sign up today and start using app</h4>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="form-group">

                    <!-- Sign up meesage errors -->
                    <div id="signupMessage">
                    </div>

                    <label for="username" class="sr-only">Username</label>
                    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" maxlength="30">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email" class="sr-only">Email</label>
                    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Adress" maxlength="50">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="password" class="sr-only">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Choose a password" maxlength="20">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="password2" class="sr-only">Confirm Password</label>
                    <input type="password2" name="password2" id="password2" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm password" maxlength="20">

                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                    <input class="btn blue" name="signup" type="submit" value="Sign up">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"> Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<form method="post" id="loginform">
<div class="modal" id="loginModal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header"></div>
            <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 id="myModalLabel">Login :</h4>

            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="form-group">

                    <!-- Sign up meesage errors -->
                    <div id="loginMessage">

                    </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="loginemail" class="sr-only">Email</label>
                    <input type="email" name="loginemail" id="loginemail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Adress" maxlength="50">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="loginpassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" name="loginpassword" id="loginpassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" maxlength="20">
                </div>

                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label><input type="checkbox" name="rememberme" id="rememberme">Remember me</label>

                    <a class="pull-right " style="cursor: pointer;"  data-dismiss="modal" href="#forgotpasswordModal"  data-toggle="modal">Forgot Password ?</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <input class="btn blue" name="login" type="submit" value="Login">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"> Cancel</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-left" data-dismiss="modal" data-target="#singupModal" data-toggle="modal"> Register</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

```
<form method="post" id="forgotpasswordform">
<div class="modal" id="forgotpasswordModal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header"></div>
            <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 id="myModalLabel">Forgot Password ? Enter your email address : </h4>

            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="form-group">

                    <!-- Sign up meesage errors -->
                    <div id="forgotMessage">

                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="loginemail" class="sr-only">Email</label>
                        <input type="email" name="loginemail" id="loginemail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Adress" maxlength="50">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <input class="btn blue" name="login" type="submit" value="Login">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"> Cancel</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-left" data-dismiss="modal" data-target="#singupModal" data-toggle="modal"> Register</button>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DEMO ATTACHED: The end div tag in the login and forget password modal is missing also put your form inside the modal just for better syntax.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#loginModal").on("show.bs.modal",function(){
$("#singupModal").modal("hide");
});
$("#forgotpasswordModal").on("show.bs.modal",function(){
$("#loginModal").modal("hide");
});
});
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#singupModal">
        singupModal
    </button>

    <div class="modal" id="singupModal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="singupModal" aria-hidden="true">

        <form method="post" id="singupform">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header"></div>
                    <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 id="singupModal">Sign up today and start using app</h4>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="form-group">

                            <!-- Sign up meesage errors -->
                            <div id="signupMessage">
                            </div>

                            <label for="username" class="sr-only">Username</label>
                            <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" maxlength="30">
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="email" class="sr-only">Email</label>
                            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Adress" maxlength="50">
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="password" class="sr-only">Password</label>
                            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Choose a password" maxlength="20">
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="password2" class="sr-only">Confirm Password</label>
                            <input type="password2" name="password2" id="password2" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm password" maxlength="20">

                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <input class="btn blue" name="signup" type="submit" value="Sign up">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"> Cancel</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginModal">
                            loginModal
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

    <div class="modal" id="loginModal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="loginModal" aria-hidden="true">
        <form method="post" id="loginform">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header"></div>
                    <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 id="loginModal">Login :</h4>

                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="form-group">

                            <!-- Sign up meesage errors -->
                            <div id="loginMessage">

                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="loginemail" class="sr-only">Email</label>
                                <input type="email" name="loginemail" id="loginemail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Adress" maxlength="50">
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="loginpassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
                                <input type="password" name="loginpassword" id="loginpassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" maxlength="20">
                            </div>

                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <label><input type="checkbox" name="rememberme" id="rememberme">Remember me</label>

                                <a class="pull-right " style="cursor: pointer;" data-dismiss="modal" href="#forgotpasswordModal" data-toggle="modal">Forgot Password ?</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <input class="btn blue" name="login" type="submit" value="Login">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"> Cancel</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-left" data-dismiss="modal" data-target="#singupModal" data-toggle="modal"> Register</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

    <div class="modal" id="forgotpasswordModal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="forgotpasswordModal" aria-hidden="true">
        <form method="post" id="forgotpasswordform">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header"></div>
                    <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 id="forgotpasswordModal">Forgot Password ? Enter your email address : </h4>

                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="form-group">

                            <!-- Sign up meesage errors -->
                            <div id="forgotMessage">

                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="loginemail" class="sr-only">Email</label>
                                <input type="email" name="loginemail" id="loginemail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Adress" maxlength="50">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <input class="btn blue" name="login" type="submit" value="Login">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"> Cancel</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-left" data-dismiss="modal" data-target="#singupModal" data-toggle="modal"> Register</button>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: Its not missing, i couldnt get all codeit inside the code snippet of this forum.

Comment: I have put the form tag inside the div of the modal also have closed the previous opened modal before opening a new one programmatically.